# Don't working the library from GitHub in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github, gradle

Don't working this [library](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) from GitHub in Android Studio
My build.gradle(:project):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
     compileSdkVersion 23
     buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

   defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.mymaterialdialogs"
      minSdkVersion 15
      targetSdkVersion 23
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
         release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
    }
}
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

  compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.4.2@aar') {
      transitive = true
  }
}
```

And My build.gradle(:app):

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
   }
}
allprojects {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
   }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Show this Error:

> Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.4.2 Show in
>   File(openFile:.../app/build.gradle)
> Show in Project Structure
>   dialog(open.dependency.in.project.structure)

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong, you are adding you dependencies in (:project) Gradle file that are supposed to be in (Module : app) Gradle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following steps:

1.In your build.gradle(:project) Add the following before dependencies

```
repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.4.2@aar') {
     transitive = true
}
}
```

2.In your build.gradle(:app): replace

```
 maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } with jcenter()
```

3.Sync project

Hope this helps.