# Failed to resolve: com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.8

Tags: android

I would like to use this library :

```
 com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons
```

but I got this message :

```
Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.8
<a href="openFile:D:/Users/****/AndroidStudioProjects/****/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

---

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.8')
    ...

}
```

inside project's `build.gradle` :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe this will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228065/dont-working-the-library-from-github-in-android-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `build.gradle` (project)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

and in your `build.gradle` (app) try this:

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.8@aar') {
    transitive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: PS. adding it here in case someone comes here now.
You can use the updated dependency in your project by just adding the following to your app level gradle file:
`compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.1.0'`

Answer (score 0):

From the [link here](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)

Firstly you have to include `Jitpack` (which i think you forgot):

```
repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```

than dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.8@aar') {
    transitive = true
    }
}
```